# How to implement multiple sort/secondary sort in the ExtJS PivotGrid?

Tags: extjs, extjs6.2

The ExtJS Grid has multiple sort/secondary sort (sort by one column by clicking on that column's header, then ctrl-click on another column's header to add a secondary sort by that second column) implemented by default.

It doesn't look like the ExtJS Pivot Grid has this implemented.  Before I try to copy/adapt the regular grid's logic into the Pivot Grid, I'd like to know if anyone has already come up with the solution for this.  If so, would you please be so kind as to share it?

Thanks!